# iOS 7.0.4 Bluetooth LE Central can't Discover Services. Some work around?

Tags: ios7, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

iOS 7.0.4 has problem with discovering services from peripherals. Older versions of iOS 7 works fine. This is apple's bug. Does anyone has some work around?

Comment: What do u mean problems? Where's the documentation on the Apple bug? How do you reproduce?

Comment: Did you try discover services with LightBlue.app?

Comment: appears similar to a problem i answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379407/bluetooth-low-energy-app-failed-to-write-characteristics-on-ios-7/20557263#20557263

Comment: It seems that the problem is only with iphone 5s

Comment: I think there are multiple bugs related to discovering BTLE services, so you should be more specific than "has a problem".  I'm seeing one in 7.0.6 on a Mini (which probably happens in 7.0.4 too).

Answer (score 3):

In my own experience there is no problems discovering services unless the corebluetooth stack has crashed. Try turning Bluetooth Off and On again.
If you test using X-code and force the app to stop then it can cause CoreBluetooth to crash in rare cases. This was much worse in early iOS6 version.